# How to set up UIScrollView programatically to scroll horizontally using autoLayout

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to acheve a behavior where i have a form in a table view with a minimum width. So basically, if the screen i wide, the view only scrolls vertically but when the screen is narrow, the form shrinks to its minimum width and then starts to scroll horizontally as to not loose content. So, I need to use autoLayout to set up these constraints and I want to do it programatically (because of frameworks I'm using).

The problem is, I can't get my view to scroll horizontally AT ALL. I have read all I could find about it, and tried everything I could think of, nothing works. Right now I try to just add a large picture to my view and make it scroll both directions, but I can't make it work.

This is my hierarchy:

```
>UIView
>>UIScrollView
>>>ContentView (UIView)
>>>>ImageView
```

And this is my code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    if scrollView == nil {
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
        scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    }
    if scrollView.superview == nil {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        let contentView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        let a = contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)
        let b = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
        a.priority = .defaultLow
        b.priority = .defaultLow
        a.isActive = true
        b.isActive = true

        let image = MyImage.icon(named: "myImage", of: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

    }
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

When I debug the view hirearchy, I can see that the size of the image is still correct `(1000, 1000)` but the content size of the scrollView isn't updated and the picture is truncated, with no scroll.

```
<UIScrollView: 0x11ead5c00; frame = (0 0; 834 1112); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c8853800>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c8c32240>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {834, 1112}; adjustedContentInset: {64, 0, 0, 0}>

<UIImageView: 0x11a89b000; frame = (0 0; 1000 1000); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c8231c80>>
```

I found and looked at this example to setup a scrolling view programatically https://github.com/zaxonus/AutoLayScroll. It scrolls vertically, but for this either, I can't for my life set it up to scroll horizontally.

Please help, what am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your example `scrollView` content size be 1000x1000 just add these constraints to `imageView`:

```
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Without them your `contentView` doesn't know it should wrap `imageView` so its' size is calculated according to low priority constraints `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anton, I got it working! I just thougt i'd share my final solution if anyone else is trying to do what I wanted.

With the below code you can add horizontal scroll functionality to the forms of the Eureka frameworks FormViewController (https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka).

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class MyScrollableViewController: FormViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var minimumWidth: CGFloat = 500.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if tableView == nil {
            tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .grouped)
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
            }
        }
        if scrollView == nil {
            scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
            scrollView.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
            scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        }
        if scrollView.superview == nil && tableView.superview == nil {
            view.addSubview(scrollView)

            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

            let contentView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
            scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

            contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

            let a = contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)
            let b = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
            a.priority = .defaultLow
            b.priority = .defaultLow
            a.isActive = true
            b.isActive = true

            contentView.addSubview(tableView)
            tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: minimumWidth).isActive = true
        }
        // Has to be called after setting up the tableView since we override the Eureka default setup
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup your Eureka form as usual
        form +++ Section()
            <<< LabelRow { row in
                row.title = "My first row"
        }
    }
}
```